# Profile WPF Control instantiation performance

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, templates, data-binding

Is there a good way to test the performance of instantiating my controls, specifically in respects of `DataBinding` and `Templates` performance?

I would like to know how much time **applying the template** and **initializing the data binding** takes.

I am using both WPF Performance Suite and ANTS Profiler but neither seems to provide information on these aspects.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the profiling tools(I have come across) have that kind of capability. Regarding binding I have found this post/article useful -

> Detecting Bindings that should be
>   OneTime:
>   http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/10/detecting_bindings_that_should_be_onetime.html
>
> Optimizing Performance: Data Binding:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx